# SSIS Delete and Recreate Destination Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I was creating a trigger and accidentally ran it on production instead of testing. I have a backup where no information will be lost in this specific table, but I only need to restore this single table.

Using SSIS how can I simply:

- Only update a single column to make it match the backup table. -or
- Drop and recreate the table exactly the same as the one I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I am assuming you have a database back up]
If you have a QA or Dev environment you could restore your production copy on it and then use SSIS to update using SCD or do a truncate/delete and copy the data over

Comment: What I eventfully did was restore the entire database back to my development machine. After that I created a new table within the production database and transferred the restored table to it. I then ran an update statement to correct the broken column from the new table